# Call javascript function using js filename

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I have two js files . One makes use of `prototype` syntax and the `jQuery`. Somehow they don't work together. I can try to call the functions inside the files using the filename.functionname something like that.

Please tell me the syntax to do so OR is there any other way to make `protoype` and `jQuery` run together since some part of their syntax clashes.

Answer (score 3):

You can't call function by the file name.

Use jquery [noCoflicts](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Short example from the docs:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is recommended not to use more than one javascript library at the same page, there are a lot of reasons for that, but as I see it the most important is: why load 2 different frameworks? they usually are quite big in size and in most cases have a lot of shared functionality.

You can however try to do so with this: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

As for the syntex to call a method using the file name, that does not exist. Once the browser loads javascript code it adds it to the global scope of the document.
What you can do is put things inside "namespaces", something like:

```
var MyNamespace = {
  methodA: function() {
    // do something
  },
  methodB: function() {
    // do something
  }
};

MyNamespace.method();
```

The problem though is that you are using 3rd party libraries which are not wrapped in namespaces, at least not all of their code.

Comment: That depends how you look at things, it's a good practice with js to try to lower the bytes you load and the number of requests you are making, if you have a simple site with little traffic then fine, it matters not, otherwise (and the bigger it gets) every byte counts. Also, people rarely use just the core of jQuery.

Comment: We use three separate frameworks. JQuery backbone and underscore. Many frameworks are specifically designed to work together. Underscore and jQuery share some functionality, but each has it's own unique sets of functionality.

Comment: And the best way to reduce overhead and latency is to use something like the google or ms hosted instances of jQuery. Since a ton of sites use them are frequently already cached. For other frameworks we use some custom code on our source control end that combines and minifies only the code needed for a specific page to run.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the fact that you're doing it doesn't make it a good practice. If they share similar functionality then you ask your user to load more than he needs to.  Using hosted versions of the libraries has pros and cons to it.

Comment: @NitzanTomer StackOverflow uses the google cached version of jQuery.  Many sites use these hosted versions.  Also, it is very commonly accepted good practice to compress and combine all your JS and CSS files as to reduce the number of extraneous calls that your page is making (lowering load overhead).  Calling seventeen different JS files instead of one is going to kill your load time.  Additionally you don't want to include code on a page you're not using (dead weight).

Comment: @NitzanTomer http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/, http://docs.jquery.com/Sites_Using_jQuery, http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html, http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rtt.html -- seriously the number of sites that explain that those are all standard good practices is manifest.

Comment: Combining all of your js code and css code into compact files is exactly what is needed to be done, though if you're loading your js from google then you can't combine that for example with the rest of your code.. that's one of the disadvantages of it, another is that you are becoming depended on a 3rd party service, which limit you.

Comment: As for all the links you provided, I never argued about the popularity of jQuery, though I'm not a fan of that library, I'm sad to admit that it's by far the most popular one. And again, all of the suggestions they make in the performances tutorials are true, but you don't need to use hosted versions for that.

Comment: @NitzanTomer - what I'm pointing out is that it's not best practice "because I happen to do it," but rather it's best practice because it's whats recommended across the board as a method.  And no, I can't combine my JS with the Google hosted version, but since the Google version is virtually guaranteed to be cached (and if not, it's immediately available, globally, local to the user), our pages are pulling one minimized file.

Comment: But, regardless.  Enjoy your http://red.bikeshed.org.  I'll enjoy my http://black.bikeshed.org

Comment: Yeah, many people think that it's good practice, and in a lot of cases they (and you) are right, it all depends on the situation.  For small web-sites, blogs etc it works really well, for big, complex web applications I would advise against it.  But again, those are different approaches.  Can I go with the black and you take the red? Red just doesn't suit me that well.